# Docker-Compose build fails [Permission Denied] with postgresql unless it uses a cached Dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, python-3.7

Thanks for taking the time to read this post!

I'm currently building an application that makes use of Python, Flask, Docker, Docker-compose and Postgres on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Previously, docker-compose build would succeed and everything was working according to plan. However, now that I switched to another Dockerfile, and I'm not using the cached version of the previous Dockerfile anymore, the build breaks with the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-37.pyc.140409285875056'
dpkg: error processing package python3.7-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.7-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.7-minimal
```

I have tried the following (Stackoverflow) posts:

- ["PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages'" installing Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950254/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-usr-lib-python3-5-site-package)
- [docker-compose , PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/manage.py'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784492/docker-compose-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-manage-py)
- [How to change permissions for a folder and its subfolders/files in one step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-change-permissions-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolders-files-in-one-step)
- [pip install failing with: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory)
- [docker-compose up && docker-compose build : error with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931621/docker-compose-up-docker-compose-build-error-with-postgresql)
- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1

but alas, to no avail.

I'm using the following files:

**Dockerfile.prod**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.0-slim-buster

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV FLASK_ENV production
ENV APP_SETTINGS src.config.ProductionConfig

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql\
  && apt-get clean

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . .

# add and run as non-root user
RUN adduser --disabled-password myuser
USER myuser

# run gunicorn
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT manage:app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    entrypoint: ['/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh']
    volumes:
      - .:/user/src/app
    ports:
      - 5004:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=src.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@api-db:5432/api_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@api-db:5432/api_test
    depends_on:
      - api-db

  api-db:
    build:
      context: ./src/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

**./src/db/Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:13-alpine

ADD create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Thanks once again for taking the time to read through this question, and if any additional information is required (e.g. a minimum viable Flask program to reproduce) please let me know!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
I have the exact same issue and this post along with https://stackoverflow.com/q/67937163/13579256 are the only places I can find the same `python3.7-minimal` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure docker belongs to your user groups:

```sh
$ groups
$ foo adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```

If that's not the case, try to create a docker group:

```sh
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

You might receive the message: `groupadd: group 'docker' already exists`

Cool, now add your user to the docker group:

```sh
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Check if docker belongs to your user group:

```sh
$ groups
$ docker adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare foo
```

You most likely need to logout and login back again.

Even if after that docker is not listed among the groups your user belongs to try:

```sh
$ newgrp docker
```

- [How to Fix Docker Permission Denied Error on Ubuntu](https://linuxhandbook.com/docker-permission-denied/)